# Python splitting dict by value of one of the keys IndexError: index 141 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, dictionary, split

This question is an addendum to one that has already been asked: [Splitting dict by value of one of the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099557/splitting-dict-by-value-of-one-of-the-keys)

I have a dictionary that has 19 keys and each key contains an array of 51000 values or observations.  One of the keys is a grouping/classification key and its value can be either 1 or 2.  What I would like to do is split the dictionary into two new dictionaries.  One for when the classification key is 1 and another one for when the classification is 2.

```
data = {'variable 1': array([ 90, 91, 89, ...
           .
           .
           .
       'variable 18': array([0.1, 0.02, 0.4, ...
       'classifier': array([1, 1, 2, ...
       }
```

I have tried doing the solution posted by georgesl for the question mentioned above:

```
data1 = [ { key : data[key][idx] for key in data.keys() }  for idx, x in enumerate(data["id"]) if x == 1 ]
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
 IndexError: index 141 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I also tried to convert the arrays to a list using:

```
data2 = {}
for key in data.keys():
     data[key] = data[key].tolist()
```

But this yields the following error when I run it through the posted solution:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am probably missing something really obvious but can't for the life of me figure out what.  I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: Array sizes are different in your data. Try: `size = len(data['classsifier']); assert all(len(a) == size for a in data.values())` (it should produce `AssertionError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something different, hope you don't mind. I believe it works:

```
from itertools import compress
data2={key:list(compress(data[key],[i-1 for i in data['classifier']])) for key in data.keys()}
data1={key:list(compress(data[key],[i-2 for i in data['classifier']])) for key in data.keys()}
```

It is my first time using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) so I am not an expert. Anyway, it works like a mask so something like:

```
>>> list(compress(['no','yes'],[False, True]))
```

gives:

```
['yes']
```

Also, if

```
data ['classifier'] = [1, 1, 2]
```

then

```
[i-1 for i in data['classifier']]
```

gives:

```
[0, 0, 1] #evaluates to [False,False,True]
```

and

```
[i-2 for i in data['classifier']]
```

gives:

```
[-1, -1, 0] #evaluates to [True,True,False]
```

Now, assuming you wanted 0 and 1 in classifier and if the classification key is 0 you have data1, this is your code:

```
data2={key:list(compress(data[key],[i for i in data['classifier']])) for key in data.keys()} # or just data['classifier']
data1={key:list(compress(data[key],[i + anything for i in data['classifier']])) for key in data.keys()}
```

Comment: This works and is a very elegant solution.  I have a quick followup question regarding the i-1 and i-2 criteria.  Is the condition executed if i-1 == 0?  If I change my classified to a range of 0 and 1 should I have i-0 and i-1 as the conditional?