# Python how to split a dict with nested values given presence of specific values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, split

I am using Python 2.7 and trying to split a dict containing nested values into multiple dicts containing specific values.  My initial dict is as follows:

```
d = {'V1': [['10', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', ['5', 'AND', '1']], 'V2': ['4', 'OR', '1'], 'V3': ['4', 'AND', '4'], 'V4': ['100']}
```

I am trying to get:

```
d1 = {'V1': [['10', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', ['5', 'AND', '1']]} #nested key:values containing OR, AND operators

d2 = {'V2': ['4', 'OR', '1']} #key:values containing only OR operator

d3 = {'V3': ['4', 'AND', '4']} #key:values containing only AND operator

d4 = {'V4': ['100']} #key:values containing no linking OR, AND operators
```

I have tried list comprehension but get stuck with separating the nested values containing both AND, OR operators.  For example:

```
OR_dict = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if 'OR' in v}
# {'V1': [['10', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', ['5', 'AND', '1']], 'V2': ['4', 'OR', '1']}
```

For separating key:values containing only AND operator I have tried the following and have had some success:

```
AND_dict = {k:v for k, v in d.items() for i in v if i=='AND'}
# {'V3': [['4', 'AND', '4']}
```

I have looked at related questions: [python split dict by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233617/python-splitting-dict-by-value-of-one-of-the-keys-indexerror-index-141-is-out-o?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [python split dict by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099557/splitting-dict-by-value-of-one-of-the-keys?noredirect=1&lq=1) but haven't been able to solve my problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Huh... it seems like you want to split the top level keys into separate dicts... am I wrong?

Comment: Anyway, what you're doing isn't good practice... strive to keep things in a single dictionary.

Comment: The original dict is generated by parsing a file that contains multiple occurrences of keys:nested values.  I'd like to bin them into separate dicts as I need to process values based on the presence of OR, AND operators.