# Split dict by value of one of the keys(To save it as a single data)

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

[My data and issue are similar as this, but it's not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099557/splitting-dict-by-value-of-one-of-the-keys)

How to split dict by value of one of the keys and save it as a single data in PostgreSQL? I have a dictionary as below:

```
data = {
    "id": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
    "info": ["info1"],# one or more than one item, number >= 1       
    "number": [1],# one or more than one item, the numbers are the same as info's  
}
```

I want to split it in one by id, keeping the respective info and number, and to save it as a single data in PostgreSQL as below:

```
 {'id': 1, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 2, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 3, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 4, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 5, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 6, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 7, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 8, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
```

if `"info"` of data has more than two info, `"info":["info1", "info2"]`, `"number"` should be `[1, 2]` too. Then data1 should be as below:

```
 {'id': 1, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 2, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 2, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 3, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 3, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 4, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 4, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 5, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 5, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 6, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 6, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 7, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 7, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
 {'id': 8, 'info': 'info1', 'number': 1},
 {'id': 8, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},
```

What is a Pythonic way of doing it? Django way is better! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use product from itertools
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
id_ = data['id']
info = data['info']
number = data['number']
info_and_number = zip(info, number)
changed_data = product(id_, info_and_number)

dict_data = [
{
    'id': id_, 
    'info': info, 
    'number': number
} for id_, (info, number) in changed_data]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance Andrey! When 'info' is more than one, ['info1','info2'], I got extra data {'id': 1, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 1}, {'id': 1, 'info': 'info2', 'number': 2},  'number' is only belong to opposite 'info', can I get rid of those extra data?

Comment: I have changed the answer. I think it should work correctly

Comment: You saved my day!!!!Thank you so much,If I want to save it into table, do you know how to achieve it? Actually 'number' is the field called version of 'info', 'id' and 'info' are all manytomanyfield, 

Comment: can you show me your models? and what models you want to create?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, it works, I did it. Haha, thanks again, wish you and your family all the best, welcome to China by the way